# Vimium and Colab Integration

Tags: python, vim, jupyter, google-colaboratory, vimium

I love Colab. There are free TPUs there!
I also love vim, and use vim mode on Colab editor.
And I also love Vimium, and I simple cannot browse without it.

The problem is:
Although the vim editor on Colab is almost good enough, there is no way to navigate the outputs without reaching for the mouse, which defeats all the purpose of vim style edition, really. But if I try to use Vimium on Colab, the Esc and some other keys gets captured and there is no way to use the editor.
I can unbind some of the keys, but it seems to be no way of unbinding the Esc key, making it impossible to integrate both tools.

Is there a way to make vimium behave well with colab, or anyway for scrolling the page in a more fluid manner than just jumping from cell to cell expecting your output is not big enough to get out of the screen?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while searching for the solution to the same problem I had myself. This is probably not a complete solution, but as a workaround, I was able to mitigate the problem by excluding `<esc>` from Vimium keybindings on the Google Colab domain address and reassigning the "Unfocus current cell" functionality in Colab from `<esc>` to another keybinding. You can access the Colab keybindings with `Ctrl+M H`, and the Vimium keybinding rules can be accessed in the Vimium extension settings.